# Multiple values/parameters in a dictionary

Tags: python

I am trying to add multiple elements/parameters/values to a Python dictionary and I am stuck. I am able to add a name, number but If I want to add more, I can't. I have tried writing it as a function, but I am still stuck (I still don't fully grasp the parameters of functions and how to call them or if it's needed here).

```
def list_of_names(name, phone, address):
phonebook = list_of_names
  phonebook = {
    ["John", 938477566,10_newcomer_st],
    ["Jack", 938377264,11_newcomer_st],
    ["Jill", 947662781,12_newcomer_st]

  }
```

Comment: You seem to want *phonebook* to be a set of lists. You can't do that because lists are not hashable

Answer (score 0):

It looks as you need a List of dictionaries, and not the other way around.
Where each dict will represent a record, and the list is just a list.

```
def list_of_names(name, phone, address):
    phonebook = [
      {"name": "John", "phone": "938477566", "address": "10_newcomer_st"},
      {"name": "Jack", "phone": "938377264", "address": "11_newcomer_st"},
      {"name": "Jill", "phone": "947662781", "address": "12_newcomer_st"},
  ]
```

Another options to use dict, can be a dict of dicts, where the key would be a hash on the values:

```
phonebook = {}

def list_of_names(phonebook, name, phone, address):
    hash_key = my_hash_function(name, phone, address)
    phonebook[hash_key] = {"name": name, "phone": phone, "address": address}
```